# Code organization when using threads

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns, multithreading, static

From OOP & OOD point of view, is it good idea to define Java-threads inside of the ***static*** method or in this case it's better to use ***instance***-based method?

```
public class ThreadPool {

    public static void stringAnalysis(ArrayList<String> strData) {
        Thread t;
        t = new Thread(new SentimentAnalysis(strData));
        t.start();
    }
}

public class SentimentAnalysis implements Runnable {

    private ArrayList<String> strData;

    public SentimentAnalysis(ArrayList<String> strData) {
        this.strData = strData;
    }

    public void computeSentiment(ArrayList<String> strData) {
        StanfordNLP_forked.analyze(strData);
    }

    public void run() {
        this.computeSentiment(strData);
    }
}
```

*StanfordNLP_forked* is a forked version of *[StanfordCoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml)* for educational purpose only.  *StanfordNLP_forked.analyze(strData)* performs text analysis of the strings array and replace each string with sentimental rank value. For the moment, I just check in the debugger the result of the analysis, later I'll add some functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Best-practice threading policy in Java is now to use the ExecutorService implementations found in the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Before we go there, though, your current code should be improved. The method:

> ```
> public static void stringAnalysis(ArrayList<String> strData) {
>     Thread t;
>     t = new Thread(new SentimentAnalysis(strData));
>     t.start();
> }
> ```

creates and starts a thread. The thread that is started is a regular thread, as opposed to a daemon thread. The JVM will exit when all threads complete, or all the remaining threads are Daemon (background) threads: see [`Thread.setDaemon(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon-boolean-).

You should typically use Daemon threads (and I believe that Java has a bug in that Daemon threads should be the default).

Additionally, there is no reason to 'Declare' the `t` Thread variable before assigning to it.

Finally, for many reasons, it is nice to give threads names.

I would have the code:

```
public static void stringAnalysis(ArrayList<String> strData) {
    Thread toRun = new Thread(new SentimentAnalysis(strData), "Sentiment Analysis thread");
    toRun.setDaemon(true);
    toRun.start();
}
```

But, in reality, I would use an Executor service....

### Executors.

Executor services work best with Daemon threads too. Here's a method that creates a Daemon thread for an Executor service:

```
private static final AtomicInteger sentimentThreadID = new AtomicInteger();

public static Thread createSentimentThread(Runnable toRun) {
    String name = "Sentiment Thread " + sentimentThreadID.incrementAndGet();
    Thread myThread = new Thread(toRun, name);
    myThread.setDaemon(true);
    return myThread();
}
```

Executors have their own Runnable that they use to create the thread. When you have ***your*** runnable, you pass it to the Executor, and the Executor runs it on one of the Executor's threads.

So, you can create an ExecutorService with something like (using Java 8):

```
ExecutorService sentimentService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(
        runnable -> createSentimentThread(runnable)
    );
```

Java 7 would be slightly longer with:

```
ThreadFactory factory = new ThreadFactory() {
   @Override
   public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
     return createSentimentThread(r);
   }

};
ExecutorService sentimentService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(factory);
```

Once you have the `sentimentService`, you can run your analysis Runnables with:

```
sentimentService.submit(new SentimentAnalysis(strData));
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't know what

```
this.analyze(strData)
```

does, and someone correct me if I am missing it:

You can just do:

strData.parallelStream().forEach(s -> StanfordNLP_forked.analyze(strData))

or, if it has some sort of result value result (you do want the analysis, right?) you could use reduce (if you can combine the result) or implement a collector if you want them in a list or something

I am feeling too lazy to whip one up for your case right now, but look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html)

The whole point os j8 stream is to make parallelization trivial through the use of functional expression.

Admittedly, I am working on understanding j8 myself.

Comment: _this.analyze(strData)_ replaced with  _this.computeSentiment(strData)_ Thanks for the link, I'll check it.